# How do you activate an Anaconda environment within a Python Script?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have searched through stack overflow, but no post helped specifically with Anaconda.

I am trying to my own Command line prompt in Python. But to do that, I need to activate my Anaconda environment. I cant find anywhere on the web how to run a basic python script to be able to activate said environment. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: are you running Anaconda on linux or windows?

Comment: I am running windows.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You should be able to use the command line to activate specific environments just by typing:

```
activate environment-name
```

You will have to do use source on Linux.

```
source activate environment-name
```

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate

**EDIT (3/29/2016)**

Sorry, I misread the question. You should be able to use the call method in the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to run the shell command through a Python script.

**Edit:** A basic example of the subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(["activate", value])
```

Comment: I get that part, but I need my python script to be able to do it. Not me in my command prompt terminal.

Comment: Oh, so you are trying to activate an environment through a Python script? As far as I can tell you have to do this through the command prompt, but you should be able to use the call function in the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Ill look into this. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps!

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how to use it, But I get it now!

Comment: I'll add more details on how to set it up for future usage, but I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: Interesting, What i have done so far is:  

`call("program location here")`  

and it opened my program. But I am now trying to figure it out how to feed it arguments.

Comment: That's interesting, but you should be able to use commands so long as it is in the $PATH. Still, whatever works.

Comment: Well Im trying to just make it print hi, but Once I open the anaconda terminal, its not taking commands. and I cant Pipe it.... what is $PATH?

Comment: The PATH is the variable used that normally contains the all the commands and executables of a file. Normally, Anaconda would include itself in the PATH.

Windows: PATH
Ubuntu: $PATH

Comment: No, no, no. PATH is an environment variable used by windows to reference executables. It is the reason why you can do activate and other commands, because it references the folder it contains. I am saying that the Anaconda script should be able to be called because they should automatically add it to the PATH variable.

Comment: OH Ok I know what you are talking about now. Calling it isnt the problem, its just getting my script to type something in command prompt.

Comment: Hey @jsb I dont understand the .call function. It seems like to be able to open up command prompt, I need to give it the location for command prompt. But I cant figure out how to input something into it. I tried using Popen with stdin, but it only seemed to take a value, not a string. Would you have any idea how to handle this?

Comment: With the call command, I believe you add the the input with it. I will look more into it though to check for other solutions.

Comment: Thank you. Cause I tried, and it didnt seem to take any input command in any way I tried.

Comment: This works, but does nothing :) It changes the command prompts active environment, then exits the command prompt. (So basically what happens is: you are running your python in one process, say X.  Subprocess.call createa new process, say Y. Then Y's active environment changes, then Y terminates... :)  It is best practice to try your answers...)

Answer (score 19):

The following will work in Python 3.5 using the subprocess module:

```
subprocess.run('source activate environment-name && "enter command here" && source deactivate', shell=True)
```

Replace the "enter command here" with the command you want to run. You don't need the "source deactivate" at the end of the command but it's included just to be safe.

This will temporarily activate the Anaconda environment for the duration of the subprocess call, after which the environment will revert back to your original environment. This is useful for running any commands you want in a temporary environment.

Comment: This is a good solution but it doesn't work if you need to set shell=False.

Comment: @brianbhsu I tried using this method in windows, the following error comes up:
`CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda
activate`. Please help me out.

Comment: @r0ot293 It sounds like you may not have anaconda configured correctly. Do you have anaconda installed? If you have it installed, can you run `conda` in your shell successfully? If that works, what happens if you run `conda activate` in your shell? If it works there, then it should work in the python script.

Comment: @brianbhsu Yes I have installed conda an can run it on my shell successfully. The problem occurs when I run my script using Git Bash. It works properly when the script is executed via windows command prompt.

Comment: >@r0ot293 I have the same issue in linux. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622383/subprocess-activate-conda-environment-from-python-script) I found this code worked for me(Ubuntu)

```
import os
os.system("conda run -n <env_name> python <file_name>.py")
```

Or you can use subprocess as well

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('conda run -n <env_name> python <file_name>.py', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I need the same thing. But we CANNOT use source in subprocess in **Linux**. Here is my solution.

For a subprocess, I append the PYTHON script after a shell, in which the conda environment is setted.

```
# This is a Python code
script = 'python test.py'
cmd_dict = {
¦   ¦   'activate_env': 'activate_env_%s.sh' % (random.randint(1000,9999)),
¦   ¦   'script': script,
¦   ¦   'conda_name': conda_name,
¦   ¦   }
cmd = 'cp activate.sh {activate_env} && echo "{script}" >> {activate_env} && sh {activate_env} {conda_name}'.format(**cmd_dict)
env = {}
env.update(os.environ)
result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, env=env)
```

Here is my activate.sh,

```
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="/home/***/miniconda3"
. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
_conda_activate "$@"
```

Answer (score -3):

the steps of creating a virtual environment using conda interface:

Step 1: Check if conda is installed in your path.

```
conda -V
```

Step 2: Update the conda environment

```
conda update conda
```

Step 3: Set up the virtual environment

```
conda create -n envname python=x.x anaconda
```

Comment: Did you not read the question?!