# Change conda environment during execution

Tags: python, package, conda

I have two pieces of code that require different versions of python and versions of packages. I have two conda environments that allow each piece of code to work separately. It seems impossible to create an environment that will support both of them. Is there a way to switch conda environment during the run (in python code), so that I could execute one part using one environment and the second part using the second environment in the same script? The form and format of the result of the first part is definitely supported by the second part, so I don't see a reason why it can't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you activate an Anaconda environment within a Python Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275308/how-do-you-activate-an-anaconda-environment-within-a-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success using conda within a shell script that calls the python process. e.g. something along these lines

```
conda activate my_env_1

python some_process.py

conda deactivate

conda activate my_env_2

python some_process_2.py

conda deactivate
```

You will have to enable your shell to use conda. See this [Python - Activate conda env through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507519/python-activate-conda-env-through-shell-script)