# How can I activate Conda environment using python code?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

How can I activate a Conda environment using python code?
Here are things I tried so far but they don't seem to change my environment:

```py
import os
os.system('conda activate envname')
# Doesn't work but returns no errors.
```

```py
import os
stream = os.popen('conda activate envname')
output = stream.read()
# Doesn't work but returns no errors.
```

```py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['conda', 'activate', 'envname'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
# Doesn't work but returns no errors.
```

So how can I change my Conda environment using python, and I want it to work on all platforms (linux, mac, windows)?

**EDIT 1:**
So from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275308/how-do-you-activate-an-anaconda-environment-within-a-python-script) it seems that all I'm doing is changing the environment temporarily during the existence of the subprocess. I want a way to change it in my current running shell...

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think this is possible: if you run a python script it will run as a new process, this process can only modify the environment variable for its children (so the things it starts itself), but not for its parent (the shell).

Comment: How does conda manage to do it then? Can I add shell initialization like conda does, to make this supported?

Comment: @AhmedKhalf _Can I add shell initialization like conda does, to make this supported?_ What do you need this for?

Comment: Nothing I was just suggesting that the way conda does the initialization is how it's able to change environment variables of the current shell. You can take a look at my issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10052