# Sequentially running jupyter notebooks with different conda environments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've got 10 jupyter notebooks, each with many unique package dependencies (that conflict), so I've created a different anaconda environment for each notebook. Each notebook relies on the output of the previous one, which I store and read from local csv files.

Right now I am running each jupyter notebook manually (with their own anaconda environment) to get the final result. Is there a way to run a single script that runs the code of all the jupyter notebooks sequentially (with the correct anaconda environment for each one)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in python and use `runipy`. You just have to install it with:

```
pip install runipy
```

An example on how to use it from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/runipy/):

```
from runipy.notebook_runner import NotebookRunner
from IPython.nbformat.current import read

notebook = read(open("MyNotebook.ipynb"), 'json')
r = NotebookRunner(notebook)
r.run_notebook()
```

If you want to run each notebook in a different environment, you can activate each conda environmentfrom a python script. There are multiple ways to do so, one of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028356/14774959):

```
subprocess.run('source activate environment-name && "enter command here" && source deactivate', shell=True)
```

> Replace the "enter command here" with the command you want to run. You
> don't need the "source deactivate" at the end of the command but it's
> included just to be safe.
>
> This will temporarily activate the Anaconda environment for the
> duration of the subprocess call, after which the environment will
> revert back to your original environment. This is useful for running
> any commands you want in a temporary environment.

Comment: And its possible to use a different environment for each book? I believe that isn't really included in your answer yet.

Comment: I've added more info